# segmentation fault on printing a returned value of a function

Tags: c, string

Whenever i try to do:

```
char buffed[1024];
snprintf(buffed, sizeof(buffed), "bash.sh %s &", get_value("request-uri"));
system(buffed);
```

this is the function I use:

```
char *get_value(char *name) {
        FORMAT_NODE *node;

#ifdef DEBUG
        ASSERT(name);
#endif

        if (strlen(name) == 0)
                return EMPTY_FIELD;

        if ((node = get_field(name))) {
                return node->value;
        } else {
                return EMPTY_FIELD;
        }
}
```

Compiling is okay but whenever it should print the value it gives a segmentation fault and crashes, can someone explain me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

edit:

get_value("request-uri")  is the one im talking about and it should be a string

strstr(get_value("request-uri"), "index.php") works perfectly!

but "index.php" should come from get_value

edit2:
gdb:
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff73f3321 in __strlen_sse2 () from /lib64/libc.so.6

Comment: what's EMPTY_FIELD?  Can you also `printf("%s\n", get_value("request-uri")));`

Comment: It'd be nice if you used gdb, or some print statements to tell us where it seg faults

Comment: what's saddr?  where is it pointing to?

Comment: Is addr an int?  If so, you need %d not %s.

Comment: You should probably check if node->value is null as well.

Comment: what does get_field return? cause if it is something allocated on stack then get_value will fail.

Comment: it worked, the only problem is using "get_value("request-uri")" in snprintf... saddr does work and it is indeed a string.  get_field returns a string... strstr(get_value("request-uri"), "index.php")  works perfectly!

Comment: Marco, you should post your answer seperate and not under the question. Then you will be able to mark your own answer as correct.

Comment: i said something else worked, this time im here to answer this question

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was solved by CBIII for telling me to use gdb, the value was empty because it flushed before it was used.

get_value("request-uri")   returned    0x0